# how do I test in laravel routes where the user must be logged in

Tags: laravel, authentication, testing, routes

Hey everyone I would like to design a test for a controller and all the views that go with it.

All views that lead to the route are secured, meaning the user has to log in before.

But somehow I do not get further.
What I have tried so far:

`$this->actingAs($user)->get('/excel'); // status error 500`

or

`$this->actingAs($user)->withSession(['banned' => false])->get('/excel'); // status error 500`

Info:

1. user was created via factory
2. the route "/excel" works (no any error, checked via browser login > to route > "excel")

My Code (testCase):

```
private function authorize()
{
    return User::factory()->create([
        'password' => bcrypt('password'),
    ]);
}

public function test_profile_view()
{
    $user = $this->authorize();
    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('/excel');
    $response->assertSuccessful();
}
```

file (Routes) /web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:sanctum']], function () {
    Route::resource('excel', ExcelController::class);
  });
```

thanks for the tips and help

Comment: $this-actingAs($user, 'sanctum'); $this->get('/excel');

Comment: unfortunately not working for me...

Comment: check error message from response

Comment: Error 500 is not your user is not authenticated but some code that is not working.

Comment: before using `actingAs()` you need to login the user with `Auth::login($user)`. I would advice to also use `$this->assertAuthenticatedAs($user)` check after `Auth::login()`

Comment: @SuperDJ the auth is working and the "$this->assertAuthenticatedAs($user)" is also correct, but the test fails after that when it comes to the actingAs()  part... =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi guys thank you very much,
everyone was right and i had to throw the tips together to solve my problem.

Problem 1.)
Display error:
was solved by `$this->withoutExceptionHandling();`.

Problem 2.)
Error in detected as no relationship has been created before.

Here is my solution to the problem, I hope it helps other people in the future.

```
private function authorize()
{
    /**
     * user id is stored in the teams table!
     */
    return User::factory()
        ->hasAttached(
            Team::factory() // create the relationship for user!
                ->state(function (array $attributes, User $user) {
                    return ['user_id' => $user->id, 'personal_team' => true];
                },
                )
        )->create();
}

public function test_profile_view()
{
    $this->withoutExceptionHandling(); // show error message

    $user = $this->authorize(); // main error begins here! but will trigger later!

    $response = $this->actingAs($user)->get('/excel'); // error happens here, there is a navigation bar which needs user and a !relationship!

    $response->assertSuccessful(); // status is always 500 because relationship is missing.
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help, without you I think I would never have got further <3
@Maksim, @mrhn and @SuperDJ